# Outlook 2003 flash/hangs when creating/replying a message

Tags: outlook-2003

I'm experiencing this issue with our Marketing VP's laptop for weeks... When he is in Outlook 2003 SP3, in the inbox, Outlook hangs for a second and flash. The cursor flashes also. It's like a very quick refresh of the inbox but that freeze the application.

I've installed all the updates related to Office 2003. I have uninstall the IntelliPoint and Intellikeyboard applications installed. That fixed the problem for few days but now it comes back again.

If you have any clue that could fix the problem, that would be great.

- The Video Software is up to date
- Microsoft Windows XP Professional 5,1,2600 SP3
- Laptop: LG E300-A.CPB3A9
- 3GO Ram
- CPU: Intel Core Duo T5550 1.83Ghz

Thank you!
D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check (and disable if ON) Outlook option to use Microsoft Word as mail editor.
If it helps - it's time to "repair" Word, e.g. disable automatic grammar checks and so on...

Comment: This seems to have fixed the problem. It's not flashing anymore. I did think that it could be that easy.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be a problem with the signatures. Try disabling them and see if it helps.